# Conditional filtering of ndarrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Suppose I have the following array of arrays:

```
Input = np.array([[[[17.63,  0.  , -0.71, 29.03],
         [17.63, -0.09,  0.71, 56.12],
         [ 0.17,  1.24, -2.04, 18.49],
         [ 1.41, -0.8 ,  0.51, 11.85],
         [ 0.61, -0.29,  0.15, 36.75]]],


       [[[ 0.32, -0.14,  0.39, 24.52],
         [ 0.18,  0.25, -0.38, 18.08],
         [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
         [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
         [ 0.43,  0.  ,  0.3 ,  0.  ]]],


       [[[ 0.75, -0.38,  0.65, 19.51],
         [ 0.37,  0.27,  0.52, 24.27],
         [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
         [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
         [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ]]]])

Input.shape
(3, 1, 5, 4)
```

Together with this `Input` array is the corresponding `Label`  array for all input, so  that:

```
Label = np.array([0, 1, 2])

Label.shape
(3,)
```

I need some way to check with all nested arrays of `Input`, to select ONLY the array with sufficient data points.

By this I mean I want a way to eliminate (or should I say delete) all arrays whose entries of the last 3 rows are all zeros. While doing this also, eliminate the corresponding `Label` for that array.

**Expected output:**

```
Input_filtered
array([[[[17.63,  0.  , -0.71, 29.03],
         [17.63, -0.09,  0.71, 56.12],
         [ 0.17,  1.24, -2.04, 18.49],
         [ 1.41, -0.8 ,  0.51, 11.85],
         [ 0.61, -0.29,  0.15, 36.75]]],


       [[[ 0.32, -0.14,  0.39, 24.52],
         [ 0.18,  0.25, -0.38, 18.08],
         [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
         [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
         [ 0.43,  0.  ,  0.3 ,  0.  ]]]])

Label_filtered
array([0, 1])
```

What's the trick that I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this with vectorized numpy commands only.

```
filter_ = np.any(Input[:, :, -3:], axis=(1, 2, 3))
labels_filtered = Label[filter_]
inputs_filtered = Input[[filter_]]
```

For the example set you provided this yields 4.95 µs ± 9.69 ns per loop (100000 loops each) compared to the solution of anon01 with 17.1 µs ± 111 ns per loop (100000 loops each). The Improvment should me even more noteable on larger arrays.

If your data has a different dimension you can change the axis argument.
For an arbitrary number of axis it could look like the following:

```
filter_ = np.any(Input[:, :, -3:], axis=tuple(range(1, Input.ndim)))
```

Comment: beat me to it :).  For OP, this is likely to be significantly faster as N_subarrays gets big.  Note: it's inadvisable to overwrite `filter`

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this depends on the scale of your data.  If there are few sub-arrays (thousands or less) you can generate a filter list that is applied to the Label and Input arrays:

```
filter = []
for j in range(len(Input)):
    arr = Input[j,:,-3:]
    filter.append(np.any(arr))
Label_filtered = Label[filter]
Input_filtered = Input[[filter]]
```

A few things to note: the vectorized/numpy bits (`Input[j,:,-3]`, `np.any(arr)`) are *very* fast, while the native python iteration and list usage (`for j in range`, `filter.append`) are *very* slow.